# flalign inside list has extra space even after \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}

Tags: spacing, equations, margins, flalign

I have defined this environment:

```
\newenvironment{proofln}{\par \textbf{Proof}\list{}{\leftmargin=10pt\rightmargin=0pt\topsep=0pt}\item\relax}{\endlist\textbf{Q.E.D}}
```

Now I use it like this:

```
\begin{proofln}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{flalign*}
    &am + bn + (K-K) = d&\\
    &= am + K + bn - K&\\
    &= am + Kab + bn - Kab&\\
    &= a(m + Kb) + b(n - Ka)&
\end{flalign*}
\end{proofln}
\begin{proofln}
    abcd
\end{proofln}
```

And the flaign is still inserting spaces above for some reason.
The bottom proofln is also doing weird - the spacing between content and "Proof" and content and "Q.E.D" is not equal.

[image]

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reasons the `amsmath` environments insert an extra vertical space of `\baselineskip` here.  So one fix is to back up by this amount.  Below I have captured the adjustments in a new environment you can place around the equation.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{proofln}{\par\noindent\textbf{Proof}\list{}{\leftmargin=10pt\rightmargin=0pt\topsep=0pt}\item\relax}{\endlist\noindent\textbf{Q.E.D}}

\newenvironment{fixmathspace}{\abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt\vspace{-\baselineskip}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proofln}
  \begin{fixmathspace}
    \begin{flalign*}
      &am + bn + (K-K) = d&\\
      &= am + K + bn - K\\
      &= am + Kab + bn - Kab\\
      &= a(m + Kb) + b(n - Ka)
    \end{flalign*}
  \end{fixmathspace}
\end{proofln}

\begin{proofln}
  \begin{fixmathspace}
    \begin{equation*}
      x = y
    \end{equation*}
  \end{fixmathspace}
\end{proofln}

\begin{proofln}
  abcd
\end{proofln}

\end{document}
```

Note that there are short versions of the displayskips, that are usually zero plus some glue, that I have also put to zero in the above code.  They apply to the second equation above.